# WSO2 Api Manager 4.1.0 logging continuously Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = / HEALTH CHECK URL = /

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm configuring an active-active WSO2 active-active cluster where everything works as expected. However it recently started logging this continuously without any change in its configuration:

```
...
INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = / HEALTH CHECK URL = /
INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = / HEALTH CHECK URL = /
INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = / HEALTH CHECK URL = /
INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = / HEALTH CHECK URL = /
...
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is some external client/system is sending a request periodically to the APIM GW to the URL `https://GW_URL:<GW_PORT>/`. Since this request doesn't match with any API contexts the request is ignored by dispatching to the main sequence.

Most probably these requests are generated from your Loadbalancer. Load balancers do periodical probing to check the availability of the server. You should be able to get around this by adding proper Healthcheck URLs in the LB by referring [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/basic-health-checks/).

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is coming from the main sequence as in [1]. There seems to be requests that are coming to the API Manager gateway with the url https://gw_host:8243/ or http://gw_host:8280/.

As mentioned this could be coming from the Load balancer health checks or some period tasks which points to the APIM node. You can check the timestamp of the log to understand the time interval. Also if you check the http_access.log in APIM, you can get more details such as user agent. The http_access.log file can be found in repository/logs folder.

You can configure health check for one of the following URLs.

- https://gw_host:8243/services/Version
- https://gw_host:9443/services/Version

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/928b0ce3175b91a3f34c16c9d970c89d2fc37556/modules/distribution/product/src/main/conf/synapse-configs/default/sequences/main.xml#L25